# PHP using foreach to loop a set of results

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get results from a mysql database to properly format into columns, but cant figure out how to do it. The following is how i need it to look.

```
<div class="box">
<div class="row">
    <input name="1" type="radio" id="1" class="radio" />
    <label for="1">Result 1</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input name="3" type="radio" id="3" class="radio" />
    <label for="3">Result 3</label>
</div>
```

```
<div class="box">
<div class="row">
    <input name="2" type="radio" id="2" class="radio" />
    <label for="2">Result 2</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input name="4" type="radio" id="4" class="radio" />
    <label for="4">Result 4</label>
</div>
```

At the moment i can only get it to go into one column using the following:

```
<div class="box">
<?php
    foreach($roles as $row){
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '  <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio" />';
        echo '  <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Can you be more specific? I want to help you but I need an example database scheme (not your real one) and exactly what output would you like to have for your example, this would help me understand your question and will gladly write you an answer.

Comment: Hey Lanjos, im using CodeIgniter as a base, to get all the results im loading a function which has the following code  function get_roles()
 {
  $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
  return $query->result();
 }

Comment: The exact output i need is the first 2 code blocks i posted ... thats how i need the source to look once outputted

Comment: Each <div class="box"></div> is a column ... I need 2 columns but the results to be split between the columns if that makes sense, so if there are 4 results, there are 2 in each div

Comment: Could you make the title more descriptive.. doesn't really relate to the specific issue of creating a two column output.

Comment: Suggestion: If this is merely a layout problem, you may want to try to use CSS to arrange the elements the way you want, instead of outputting them in the "wrong" order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea (not factored, and I'm trying to write the most illustrative code I can...)
Basically, over each row, increment $i by one. If we have two rows, close the div, and open a new div on the next iteration.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $output = "";
    foreach($roles as $row){
        if($i > 1) {
           $i = 0;
        }
        if($i == 0) {
           // Open the div
           $output .= "<div class='box'">;
        }
        $output .= '<div class="row">';
        $output .= '  <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio" />';
        $output .= '  <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        if($i == 0) {
            // Close the div
            $output .= "</div>";
        }

        $i++;
    }
    if($i != 1) {
        // We need an extra one here, just in case the loop finished on 
        // an odd number.
        $output .= "</div>";
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this response ..... It works ok, except when it outputs it misses the <div class='box'> on the second column

Comment: The output looks like this: <div class='box'>
 <div class="row">
  <input name="_wfa" type="radio" id="wfa" class="radio" />
  <label for="wfa" style="text-transform: lowercase;">Actionscripter</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <input name="_AP1" type="radio" id="AP1" class="radio" />
 <label for="AP1" style="text-transform: lowercase;">art director</label>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Whoops! Left a bug in there, cut-and-pasted from the wrong window when I wrote the comment. However, looking at what you were after again - this isn't the solution. I misread your initial question. Sorry! :)

Comment: Is there no way we can put the tag in there?

Comment: Actually, wait on. Your question specifies that the first row should be in a box, and the second should not. The third should, the fourth should not, and so on. I've edited my submission and the output I get is:

Comment: <div class='box'><div class="row">  <input name="_Foo" type="radio" id="Foo" class="radio" />  <label for="Foo" style="text-transform: lowercase;">Foo</label></div></div><div class='box'><div class="row">  <input name="_Bar" type="radio" id="Bar" class="radio" />  <label for="Bar" style="text-transform: lowercase;">Bar</label></div></div><div class='box'><div class="row">  <input name="_Baz" type="radio" id="Baz" class="radio" />  <label for="Baz" style="text-transform: lowercase;">Baz</label></div></div> (etc) -- Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an **if** statement to check either the *key* is odd or even number. It's not a very clean solution, but:

```
<?php
    foreach($roles as $row){
        if($row->key%2 == 1) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '  <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio" />';
            echo '  <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
            echo '</div>';
        } 
    }
    echo "</div><div class=\"box\">";
    foreach($roles as $row) {
        if($row->key%2 == 0) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '  <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio" />';
            echo '  <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```